# How to add custom loading screen?

Tags: boot, image

I would like to make Raspberry PI useful for TV purpose or so... Therefore I would like to show to end user loading image before entering the X-Windows and starting customized desktop...

So instead of watching kernel loading modules I would like to switch this with GIF image or something...

Where is the best place to start to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome EW- Please form specific questions and there is no need to sign your posts. We can click on your Nickname to get more information about you. I hope you get the answer you are looking for.Please remember accept a question if it has solved your problem or lead you in the correct direction

Answer (score 31):

Custom Splash Screen for Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

This is a quick and dirty solution for an unanimated custom splash screen during boot.

First of all, you need to install fbi:

```
apt-get install fbi
```

Copy your custom splash image to /etc/ and name it "splash.png".

Next, create an init.d script called "asplashscreen" in "/etc/init.d/".

I chose "asplashscreen" with an "a" at the beginning to be sure it starts first.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          asplashscreen
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:      
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Show custom splashscreen
# Description:       Show custom splashscreen
### END INIT INFO


do_start () {

    /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash.png    
    exit 0
}

case "$1" in
  start|"")
    do_start
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
  stop)
    # No-op
    ;;
  status)
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

Then make that script executable and install it for init mode rcS:

```
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/asplashscreen

insserv /etc/init.d/asplashscreen
```

Reboot and watch your custom splash screen:

```
reboot
```

Comment: I actually prefer this solution - much simpler, less time-consuming.

Comment: Strangly, this causes a graphical glitch in the top left  corner of the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

You can take a look at [Splashy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splashy) for creating a custom loading (*splash*) screen.

I can't see it on the list of official packages, so you would have to compile it from source. It is available via `git` from [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=splashy/splashy.git).

You should be able to check out the source and build like this:

```
git clone https://anonscm.debian.org/git/splashy/splashy.git
cd splashy
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Hopefully that will build, at first glance I can't see any problem with it.
You can then follow the `README` provided with the source code (or [online here](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=splashy/splashy.git;a=blob;f=README;h=effdff4c543eaedabc01e3ad8249836d3b4e2022;hb=HEAD)) for the <s>installation</s> configuration procedure.

Comment: Does 'make install' not install it? If not, what is the difference between 'make', 'make install', and installing? Thanks.

Comment: `make` builds the executable. `make install` installs the executable, usually simply by copying it to the appropriate directory.

Comment: So in your above post you issue the command 'make && sudo make install' which should build and install the executable. However, you went on to say "You can then follow... for the installation procedure." How is installing the executable different from the installation?

Comment: @JGord Sorry, perhaps that should be the configuration procedure. After installation of the binaries you have to do things such as edit the kernel parameters and make some symlinks. The `README` contains all that information.

Comment: @JGord No problem. I've edited my answer slightly.

Comment: @Jivings Tut tut, link rot threat!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain How so? Wikipedia isn't going anywhere. And you have to get the source somewhere. And the README is available in two places.

Comment: I meant the README, but I guess if you have the source...

Comment: Jivings I can't build Splashy on rPi with your help. When I am in the ./configure step I get:
bash: ./configure: no such file or directory.

Comment: Looks like these instrection are for an eariler version of splashy, can you give details of which version worked on the pi, or update the instructions, it looks like the new version uses `configure.ac`, and dependson some other programs I can't find in debian repisotries.