# Can I boot Raspbian with a graphic splash instead of text?

Tags: raspbian, boot, gui

Is it possible to have a **Graphical Boot-up image** for Raspbian, rather than the default "text-console" interface.

By this I don't mean for logging in, but for booting up (i.e. before the DM or `login:` prompt, whilst you're getting all the `[ok]`s and `[...]`s popping up).

So instead of this...

[image]

I would like an image like Ubuntu has, but my own custom one.

[image: ubuntu boot screen]

Comment: Try reading this answer http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-to-add-custom-loading-screen. It's basically a duplicate of yours.

Comment: I think you need to change the bootloader. ubuntu uses grub? or did at least. That allows you to choose the boot screens and make options, etc. Not sure if that is supported on the Raspbian kernel. But some work might get it going. But that link does give you allof of other options. You should have searched first!

Comment: Please vote for duplicate of suggested link by RPi. The answer is there.

Comment: @ppumkin - I did search first, but nothing came up (I looked for "GUI Boot Screen", amongst others);

Comment: No problem! Best of Luck!