# Raspberry pi custom SD card image

Tags: raspbian

I have a project uses Qt GUI which works on raspberry-pi2; however I don't want users to interact with the operating system. I just want that the only application appears on the screen (from boot to shutdown) to be is my application. Actually the retropie project has done what I actually want. So I want to prepare an minimal SD Card image like that. Is there any tool or way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here're a few pointers.

1. Hide boot messages and use fbi to show custom logo / images or mplayer / omxplayer to show some animation while Rpi boots to mask background utility
   (Here is a link : [How to add custom loading screen?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-to-add-custom-loading-screen))
2. Boot to x and use openbox by modifying `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file.

Comment first 3 lines and add following two.

```
@openbox
@/path/to/qt-programme-binary
```

3. Make sure your qt program is full screen.

Important notes :

1. Do not keep your qt program source in Pi as your SD card could be physically available to others as you ship it with your product and they can plug it in to a linux box and extract your code / binary.
2. If you're so concerned about security and others using your binary / setup, you should consider device lock down on the basis of Rpi mac address or serial number embedding into your program and somewhere in start up so that it boots only with your device and hence copying your sd card image won't work on other Rpi devices.

Hope it helps.

Comment: better option 1, if it's a QT with QML app not need run X for work ... (use more memory to run X before QT)